# Maya python invalid syntax on import

Tags: python, syntax, maya

I'm doing an autorig for Maya, and I have this file which return me a invalid syntax :

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
from SupeRigTools import *

def startButtonFunc():
    loadLocators()

    buttons = ["left_leg_button", "right_leg_button"]

    for but in buttons:
        cmds.button(but, edit = True, enable = True)

def leftLegButtonFunc():
    rigLeg("left")

    cmds.button("left_leg_button", edit = True, enable = False)

def rightLegButtonFunc():
    rigLeg("right")

    cmds.button("right_leg_button", edit = True, enable = False)
```

And the error is :

```
# Error: line 1: SyntaxError: file <maya console> line 2: invalid syntax #
```

It used to work but it won't compile now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had a syntax error in the middle of my SupeRigTools file with a semicolon, but Maya didn't tell me, thank you for your answer

Comment: Go to your script editor and check `History -> Show stack trace` to get more information on your errors.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the module in your python path ?

```
import sys
sys.path.append('path/moduleFolder')
import SupeRigTools
```

Comment: Failing to load the module would throw an `ImportError`. This just seems to be a typo error, maybe a wrong space/tabulation.